# Bash Logic backwards on one system, but not another

Tags: bash, test

I have two linux systems. I am testing for the existence of a program on each system. One system has the program installed, another does not. Somehow, each system evaluates the following example the same way despite the command in `$()` returning different values on each system (0 on the system with nvim installed, 1 on the system without nvim installed, as expected).
Example:

```
if [[ $(type nvim &>/dev/null) ]]; then
    echo true;
else
    echo false;
fi
```

echoes `false` on both systems.
Why might this be, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
if type nvim &>/dev/null
then
     echo true
else
     echo false
fi
```

An `if command; then...` statement depends on the `command` returning an exit code.  The `[[...]]` command can set exit codes based on various  conditions such string equality, a file's existence, etc.  See `man bash` for details. You don't need any of those conditions here and `type` returns a useful exit code all by itself.

Comment: This did it, thank you! Never even crossed my mind that that could be how the command was being interpreted.

Comment: A more terse version: `type nvim &>/dev/null && echo true || echo false`.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong. The following:

```
if [[ $(type nvim &>/dev/null) ]]; then
```

is equivalent to this:

```
if [[ "" ]]; then
```

You can either do what you want as said [in the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/234119/72304) or be more explicit for no reason and use `$?`:

```
type nvim &>/dev/null

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo true;
else
    echo false;
fi
```